# Continuous MySQL Database Querying in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for the easiest and most sensible way to allow this scenario to occur;

User loads page --> While page is loaded it continuously queries a database until it finds a certain value is set (the users IP address) --> Once that value is set it will redirect the page.

The reason why I can't simply take the users IP on the page, insert it into the database and then redirect is because the IP address is used for a method of validation, and is passed through as a parameter to a seperate website (that I have no control over), then once the user has completed a set of actions on that website it is passed back and added into my database.

If anyone could point me in the write direction, of which PHP functions I could use and such, I would greatly appreciate it :)!

Comment: So, wait, what's that supposed to look like for the user? The user goes to another page to complete some actions but still *your* site should redirect him…? Can you describe that setup in more detail?

Comment: Alright, a full description: User enters via homepage -> User is redirected to country specific page -> User clicks on a download link -> Modular JS box popups up, requesting that he/she complete an offer in order to access said link, and has a list of offer links -> Each offer link takes the parameter of "subid" which can hold any value, in this case the users IP address is used as the value -> User clicks on offer which is opened in a new page in order for he/she to complete ->

Comment: Once completed the users IP address (the value of "subid") is posted back to another PHP script which gets the users IP address and inserts it into a whitelist database -> Module box on other page displays thank you message, redirects through to download page

Comment: How modern are the browsers that are accessing your pages? It seems like a combination of WebSockets - http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/ - and using a background processing system like Gearman - http://gearman.org/ - would help you accomplish this task. (Regardless of whether or not use can use WebSockets, I would highly recommend incorporating Gearman into your solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to keep querying on the original page is probably via AJAX. Send an AJAX request to a script on your server every 20 seconds or so to check whether the database has been updated with the data you're looking for. To make this more realtime, long-polling/Comet is a technique you may want to look into as well.

A very low-tech solution would be a simple page that keeps refreshing itself, checking the database on each load.

Using the IP as the unique identifier is not very granular though. That may give a large range of people blanket access if only one person filled out an offer. Unless that's no problem for you, it'd be better to create a long random string, save it in the session, send it along as the `subid` and wait for it to come back. That way you can identify a *user* uniquely. You could even identify specific *actions* a user took uniquely.

Hope that gets you going.